# should I migrate my question from Math.SE here?

Tags: discussion

I have asked a question regarding a solution to a differential equation I came to when trying to solve the motion equation of a single body in a gravitational potential:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/415467/how-to-solve-the-differential-equation-for-the-motion-equation-of-a-body-in-a-gr

At first I wanted to ask that question here, but since the tag [mathematical-physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathematical-physics) arges to use Math.SE:

> DO NOT USE THIS TAG just because your question involves math! If your question is on simplification of a mathematical expression, please ask it at math.stackexchange.com Mathematical physics is the application of mathematics to problems in physics and mathematical methods suitable for such applications [...]. It also includes the study of problems inspired by physics within a mathematically rigorous framework [...].

I asked the question in Math.SE, but the quaestion over-there isn't answered and doesn't get a lot of attention, I believe that it'll get better (any) answers here. Should I migrate the question from Math.SE to Physics.SE?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. You seem to have managed the physics part, so the question is just asking for a solution to a given D.E.

Besides, "how do I solve this" is sort of off topic on Physics.SE

Insted, I suggest you place a bounty on the question on MSE.

Comment: Yep, this is correct. The question would be off topic here.